# Periods in URL cause Railo Error

Tags: coldfusion, railo

The following link `http://127. 0. 0. 1:8888/.../index.cfm` causes an error in Railo's built in server.

Can anything be done to keep this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Why do you require such a url? You could address this with a web server rewrite rule also.

Comment: I don't require such a variable. I just want to make sure a that junk in the URL does not cause the page to crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to handle this by defining a onMissingTemplate function in your Application.cfc

Comment: So I would have to create an `application.cfc` above the share directory?